# In ruby, how do I attempt a block of code but move on after n seconds?

Tags: ruby

I have a library method that occasionally hangs on a network connection, and there's no timeout mechanism.

What's the easiest way to add my own?  Basically, I'm trying to keep my code from getting indefinitely stuck.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

timeout.rb has some problems where basically it doesn't always work quite right, and I wouldn't recommend using it. Check [System Timer](http://ph7spot.com/articles/system_timer) or [Terminator](http://lindsaar.net/2008/9/11/terminator-timeout-without-mercy) instead

The System Timer page in particular describes why timeout.rb can fail, complete with pretty pictures and everything. Bottom line is:

> - For timeout.rb to work, a freshly created “homicidal” Ruby thread has to be scheduled by the Ruby interpreter.
> - M.R.I. 1.8, the interpreter used by most Ruby applications in production, implements Ruby threads as green threads.
> - It is a well-known limitations of the green threads (running on top of a single native thread) that when a green thread performs a blocking system call to the underlying operating systems, none of green threads in the virtual machine will run until the system call returns.

Answer (score 4):

Answered my own question:

http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib/libdoc/timeout/rdoc/index.html

require 'timeout'
  status = Timeout::timeout(5) {
    # Something that should be interrupted if it takes too much time...
  }

Answer (score 0):

To prevent an ugly error on timeout I suggest enclosing it and using a rescue like this:

```
begin
   status = Timeout::timeout(5) do 
      #Some stuff that should be interrupted if it takes too long
   end       
rescue Timeout::Error
   puts "Error message: It took too long!\n"
end
```